# Nodejs is not working properly it is giving me type error

Tags: node.js

I Have this function :

```
const getWeb3Instance = network => {
let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(wrapConstants.constants.RPC))
if (network === 'ropsten') {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(wrapConstants.constants.ROPSTEN_RPC));
} else if (network === 'rinkeby') {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(wrapConstants.constants.RINKEBY_RPC));
} else if (network === 'fnbd') {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(wrapConstants.constants.PRIVATE_RPC));
}
return web3;
}
```

This is how I use this functions

```
 router.post('/chooseNetwork',(req,res)=> {
    const network = req.body.network
    network.length === 0 ? res.send('You must choose network') : res.send(controllers.getWeb3Instance((network)))
})
```

After sending request to this endpoint I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

I dont really understand why i am getting this error,any suggestions please?

Comment: This just means your structure you're trying to serialize has self-referential elements. `let x = { }; x.x = x` will fail to serialize.

Comment: It's worth noting that highly convoluted function could be reduced in size dramatically by using a simple look-up table to resolve the constants, then *one* call to `new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(lookup[network] || c.RPC))`

Comment: Is following code the issue? ` const wrapConstants = {
    constants,
   contracts
 }

module.exports = wrapConstants`

Comment: It's your structure. Somewhere in it something loops. Since you're dumping out a raw `Web3` thing, whatever that is, you either a) don't want to do that, or b) do want to, but only a property of it.

Comment: @tadman so basically that will shorten the code but leave the same functionality right

Comment: Yeah. Shorter code is easier to comprehend at a glance, and is less likely to be buggy because you can see the bugs more clearly. This is the core of [DRY code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @tadman the Web3 is just const Web3 = require('web3') can this really be the issue here?

Comment: The issue is whatever `new Web3(...)` produces. Some kind of self-referential object apparently. You can't just `JSON.stringify` any old thing, it has to be something that JSON can represent.

Comment: Maybe you mean to call a method on that thing once you create it? Maybe there's a missing step here? I can't tell from this code, there's not enough context, but that's a guess.